# Releasing an NSTimer iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, nstimer, timing

I have an NSTimer declared in my .h and in the viewDidLoad of the /m I have the code:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kComplexTimer target:self selector:@selector (main) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I also have [timer release]; in my dealloc.

However when I exit the view and return to it, the timer has not in fact released, it has doubles in speed! How do I solve this & what am I doing wrong???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice Answer , but good to check whether the time is nil or not to avoid unwanted exception..

```
if( timer ! = nil )
{
  [timer invalidate];
  timer = nil;
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 6):

you don't need to release it as you have not retained it - as a rule.
all you need to do is just call `[timer invalidate];` which will stop your timer.

Answer (score 2):

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

The second line is important if you want to reset the `NSTimer`

Comment: +1 The `nil` is very key. I used to have issues with timers and their reuse until adding that part.

Answer (score 1):

You must not call release on a object that it not be created by "new", "alloc", "retain", "copy".

In this case, you had created a Timer by scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval method,  So you must not call release method but call [timer invalidate] to stop the timer.